# GPG fails to retrieve passphrase

Tags: ssh, encryption, arch-linux, gnupg

When trying to do gpg (version 1) keygen on archlinux I get the following errors after details (other than passphrase) have been entered:

```
You need a Passphrase to protect your secret key.

pinentry: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
gpg-agent[5853]: can't connect to the PIN entry module: End of file
gpg-agent[5853]: command get_passphrase failed: No pinentry
gpg: problem with the agent: No pinentry
gpg: Key generation canceled.
```

I have pinentry installed on the system. It also fails when using gpg2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks as if pinentry depends on Gtk 2.0, which you appear not to have installed on your system.  Normally, the dependency management system ought to handle that, but in your case, it appears to have failed.

You have two choices.  First, installing Gtk 2.0 should solve the problem, based on the error you posted.  Second, it may be possible to build a custom version of pinentry from source that does not depend on X11.  In addition to the Gtk+ GUI, there appear to be both Qt and Curses interfaces in the repository, so you may be able to install or build one of those instead.